# Delete data from firebase by id using flutter

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, dart

I'm new with Flutter. Currently I am trying to do the CRUD. But then I got some error to delete the data by ID. I did manage to do the delete operation but then it will delete the latest inserted data instead, not the data that `onTap`. Here I attach my source code.

```
String docId;

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('taks');
    DocumentSnapshot ds;

return new StreamBuilder(
  stream: users.snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text('Loading...');

      return new ListView.builder(

          itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            ds = snapshot.data.docs[index];
            // children: snapshot.data.docs.map((document) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text(ds['task']),
              subtitle: Wrap(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Priority: " + ds['priority']),
                  Text("   |    Status: " + ds['status']),
                ],
              ),
              onTap: (){
                docId = ds.id;
                print(docId);
              },
              trailing: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.update_rounded,
                        size: 20.0,
                        color: Colors.brown[900],
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => UpdateScreen(docId)));
                      }
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.delete_outline,
                      size: 20.0,
                      color: Colors.brown[900],
                    ),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      try {
                        FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection("taks")
                            .doc(docId)
                            .delete()
                            .then((_) {
                          print("success!");
                        });
                      }
                      catch (e) {
                        print("ERROR DURING DELETE");
                      }
                      //   _onDeleteItemPressed(index);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              // subtitle: new Text(document['priority']),
            );
          });
    // );
  },
);
```

So, I tried to print the `docId` on which row that been selected. I tap all the data but it will only read the latest data id only.

[image: Firebase]
[image: Console print ID]

So can anyone help me to sort out this problem on how to delete the data that been selected only, not always delete the latest data? Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure I understand what exactly it is you want to delete, but your function tells Firebase to delete the entire document with the ID you are passing.

You also are defining `String docId' to your whole widget and using it for all your ListView.Builder items.
Try this:

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        ds = snapshot.data.docs[index];
        String docIdTobeDeleted= ds.id;
        // children: snapshot.data.docs.map((document) {
        return new ListTile(
          title: new Text(ds['task']),
          subtitle: Wrap(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Priority: " + ds['priority']),
              Text("   |    Status: " + ds['status']),
            ],
          ),
          onTap: (){
//you won't be needing this anymore, instead you can type:
         print(docIdTobeDeleted);
            //docId = ds.id;
            //print(docId);
          },
```

and for firebase below, use this:

```
onPressed: () async {
   try {
       FirebaseFirestore.instance
       .collection("taks")
       .doc(docIdTobeDeleted)
       .delete()
        .then((_) {
      print("success!");
        });
         }
         catch (e) {
       print("ERROR DURING DELETE");
        }
```

It should work.

Comment: I see. So, the problem is where i put my docId right? Thus, what I need to do is pass ID inside the itemBuilder am I right?

Comment: correct, what was happening was that every time your list build a new tile, it assing docId the id of the latest built tile is given as ID. So every entry in your list view, has the same ID... and that Id is the ID of the last tile that the list view builder rendered.

Comment: I see. Now I have a better understanding. Thank you for helping me again. I already faced this problem for 3 days actually.

Comment: You're most welcome @jat. Yes it happens sometimes, but know with everything you learn, it becomes easier. Good luck and come back for more anytime!

Answer (score 0):

your `Listtile` `onTap` will set the **docID** to the selected tileID.. and the `deleteIconButton` will delete the id of **docID**.. so if you tap on the first `ListTile` and tap on any of the `deleteIconButton`.. It will delete the first ListTile

You can use the direct ds.id instead of **docID** in the `deleteIconButton`

```
IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.delete_outline,
                  size: 20.0,
                  color: Colors.brown[900],
                ),
                onPressed: () async {
                  try {
                    FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection("taks")
                        .doc(ds.Id)
                        .delete()
                        .then((_) {
                      print("success!");
                    });
                  }
                  catch (e) {
                    print("ERROR DURING DELETE");
                  }
                  //   _onDeleteItemPressed(index);
                },
              ),
```